# SYMFONY 3.1 | TWIG - Markup.php (throwing error since migrating from 2.9.X)

Tags: exception, twig, migration, symfony, symfony-3.1

After upgrading my project from Symfony 2.9.X to Symfony 3.1.X the site has been throwing errors constantly:

[image: Error in Markup.php located in vendor/twig]

I am currently stumped on this particular issue, and cannot resolve it.

> composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "jordan/.checkout",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "httpdocs",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AppKernel.php - http://pastebin.com/aNUSYuYt
Dev Log: http://pastebin.com/DwdGGkyY
Prod Log: http://pastebin.com/iXqqudKZ

Comment: What's the code on and around line 20 of the Markup.php file? It appears you are just missing a "use" statement... The other errors appear to be about your `config.yml` so you'll need to post that as well.

Comment: Which PHP version did you use when you got this error?

Comment: PHP 7.0.15 which is latest for my server configuration, adding a 'use' statement doesn't seem to resolve the issue. The config.yml errors are warnings at the moment, these will be patched before Symfony 4 releases. However, adding a backslash \JsonSerializable resolved the issue as commented by Stephan.

Comment: What are peoples issues? A genuine question, got an answer, marked as solved. Now tons of negative downvotes getting me banned from asking questions - is this the kind of community you want to promote? Please, consider being constructive! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. I downvoted because you didn't add relevant code to your question ([as text, not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344250/is-it-ok-to-post-screenshots-with-error-messages-instead-of-copying-the-message)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) is PHP interface.

Add a backslash to use it: `\JsonSerializable` instead of `JsonSerializable` or add a use statement at top of your file (`use JsonSerializable;`).

Otherwise, it will look in your bundle (for example `AppBundle\AppBundle\Twig\JsonSerializable`, I don't know where Markup.php is located)

Comment: Thanks, adding a backslash has resolved the issue. The use statement didn't seem to work as that was my first idea. Later, I will scrap the project files and use a clean version of Symfony 3 and port over the code as too much patchwork will cause issues later on.